# how to use assertj extracting map property

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertj

I am using `AssertJ`. I have a class like `MyObj`. And I have a `List` of `MyObj`.

```java
class MyObj {
    ...
    Map<K,V> myMap;
    ...
}
```

When I use:

1. `assertThat(list).extracting("myMap")`, I cannot use `.containsKey()` method.
2. I also tried using `assertThat(list).extracting("myMap", Map.class)`, but it does not work either.

What is the right way of using it?

Comment: Why not just grab the map in a variable and use assertj on that?

Comment: @fge It is a way. But I am wondering is there any easier way to extract map property directly.

Comment: Extracting a Map property from a list of objects allows doing assertions on a list of maps. Why would you be able to use containsKey on a list of maps? A list of maps doesn't have a key.

Comment: @JBNizet Whoops!!!  Thanks a lot! It is a list of maps! I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 15):

AssertJ has entry() method.
You can assert map value like this.

```
assertThat(list)
    .extracting("myMap")
    .contains(entry("foo1", "bar1"), entry("foo2", "bar2"));
```

Here's javadoc : http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/data/MapEntry.html

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to assert the contents of your map is chaining the `extracting` method:

```
    MyObj o1 = new MyObj();
    o1.getMyMap().put("foo", "Hello");
    o1.getMyMap().put("bar", "Bye");
    MyObj o2 = new MyObj();
    o2.getMyMap().put("foo", "Hola");
    o2.getMyMap().put("bar", "Adios");

    List<MyObj> myObjs = Arrays.asList(o1, o2);
    assertThat(myObjs).extracting("myMap").extracting("foo").contains("Hello", "Hola");
    assertThat(myObjs).extracting("myMap").extracting("bar").contains("Bye", "Adios");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the `containsKey` method, you must know the type of the key at compile time (that is, you can't rely on generics). Supposing `myMap` is a `Map<String, Long>` you could do:

```
assertThat(list)
  .extracting("myMap")
  .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.map(String.class, Long.class))
  .containsKey("key");
```

Answer (score 3):

Extracting feature is documented here: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#extracted-properties-assertion

You have executable examples in [assertj-examples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/tree/master/assertions-examples), and specifically in  [IterableAssertionsExamples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java).

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

**It's a little bit more complicated, but definitely possible**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject<String, Integer> myObject1 = new MyObject<>("A", 1);
        MyObject<String, Integer> myObject2 = new MyObject<>("B", 2);
        MyObject<String, Integer> myObject3 = new MyObject<>("C", 3);

        List<MyObject<String, Integer>> myObjects = Arrays.asList(myObject1, myObject2, myObject3);

        assertThat(myObjects).extracting("myMap", Map.class).is(containingKey("A"), atIndex(0))
                                                            .is(containingKey("B"), atIndex(1))
                                                            .is(containingKey("C"), atIndex(2));
    }

    private static class MapContainsKeyCondition<K> extends Condition<Map> {
        private final K keyToContain;

        public MapContainsKeyCondition(K key) {
            this.keyToContain = key;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Map map) {
            return map.containsKey(keyToContain);
        }
    }

    private static <K> Condition<Map> containingKey(K key) {
        return new MapContainsKeyCondition<>(key);
    }

    public static class MyObject<K, V> {
        final Map<K, V> myMap;

        public MyObject(K key, V value) {
            this.myMap = Collections.singletonMap(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract `Map` from `List` and validate it's content as suggested here - [Assertj Core Features](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html), as follows:

```
@Test
public void getMyObjList() {
    assertThat(list).isNotEmpty().extracting("myMap")
            .isNotEmpty().contains(geMap());
}

private Map<String, Integer> geMap() {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    return map;
}
```